# PowerShell remove LineFeed & CarageReturn from Get-CimInstance

Tags: powershell, replace

I'm working on a new script and to make things easier for me in the long run I need to put everything manually in a form to keep track. Now I love that the list is mostly clean, but I would like the following.

I run:

```
$PrL = (Get-CimInstance -Class CIM_Printer).Name | Sort-Object
```

Result:

```
Printer01
Printer02
Printer03
Printer04
```

Output I try to achieve:

```
Printer01; Printer02; Printer03; Printer04
```

I manage to either put ; at the end of each line or to have each entry be written one after the other.

Of course I could use Notepad++ and replace "\r\n" with "; " but that takes more time. I would like to be able to automate this but so far I only get one after the other.

Here are some attempts.

Attempt 1:

```
$PrL = (Get-CimInstance -Class CIM_Printer).Name | Sort-Object
$PrL2 = ForEach-Object { $PrL -replace '\r', ' '}
```

Attempt 2:

```
$PrL = (Get-CimInstance -Class CIM_Printer).Name | Sort-Object
$PrL2 = $PrL | ForEach { $_ +  "; " }
$PrL2 | ForEach { $_ -replace '\r', ' '}
```

Attempt 3:

```
$PrL = (Get-CimInstance -Class CIM_Printer).Name | Sort-Object
$PrL | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace '\n', " "}
```

I don't even know if \r or +r or `r or something else entirely is required and I basically tried copy paste some things that people have tried but those only work in parts or not at all.

Current PowerShell Version: 5.1.19041.3930
OS: Windows 10 Pro

Comment: To start: what is the point of this formatting? to get it on screen or on a file?

Comment: @sirtao the point would be that once I am able to replace the line feed and carage return, I can put it in a database with any separator of my choice.

Comment: so you want to put them together to later load them in a DB as a single string, is that correct?

Comment: @sirtao yes. Currently with my old script I would get a list with spaces and multiple CR and LF but it's limited to the language I used. Mathias has solved the issue for me tho. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the pattern `\r?\n` instead - by marking the `\r` optional with `?` it'll match both CRLF and LF-style line endings:

```
(Get-CimInstance -Class CIM_Printer).Name -replace '\r?\n',' '
```

---

Based on your listed output it doesn't look like any of the printer names have any line breaks in their names.

If you want to take an existing array of string values and *join* them into a single string, use the `-join` operator:

```
$semiColonSeparatedListOfPrinterNames = (Get-CimInstance -Class CIM_Printer).Name -join '; '
```

`$semiColonSeparatedListOfPrinterNames` will now print on a single line

Comment: Didn't work for me. Does it work for you when you try?
I just entered it as you posted and nothing different happened. Almost as if Powershell puts something else there. I could create a txt file but that defeats the purpose a little bit.

Comment: @VarmintLP I suspect you may have asked a different question than the one you want an answer to - see updated answer :)

Comment: Thank you Mathias, that has solved my issue and it would also explain why nothing worked. This even removed the need to replace "; " at the end of the line.